# Public diff files from git using jenkins over ftp

Tags: git, ftp, jenkins

I'm starting to use jenkins and I'm using it to pull from git one repository and publishing to a FTP using Publish over FTP plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+FTP+Plugin).

The problem is that the REPO is growing a lot of and it has media files (img, sounds...) and in the configuration that I have, it is deleting all on the ftp and then uploading all again.

I would like to publish only the diff files (the update files from the last build) and I don't know where to start.

Anyone can guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I finally did manually with a PHP Script launched after the building.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your script? We want to do the same thing. Many thanks

Comment: Hi Martin! Let me know exactly the environment that you have and I help you to do it

Comment: Sorry have only just seen your comment.  Yes it woudl be great if you could help!  We have Jenkins on a windows server with a job to poll a GIT repo on bitbucket (which holds a php project).  When a commit happens we want to get the files and upload to a hosting site via SCP.  It's all working fine apart from we need a bit in the middle to work out the changes (including deletes) and only apply those via SCP.  My mail is martin.rolph at oval.uk.com if that helps. Thanks!